# Find a pattern in XML using unix command

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, xml

I have XML like below

```
<a>
</a>
<a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
</a>
```

I need to find line numbers of the empty tags which are in two consecutive lines without any tags in between them like below.

```
    <a>
    </a>

Output: 1 -> line number
```

I'm using PCGREP but my unix admins have restricted or not supporting perl commands hence can this be achieved using SED or AWK? 
Note: xmlstarlet is not supported too.

Comment: XMLStarlet and the grep utility you refer to are the best options for solving this. On a Unix system, virtually any software may be installed in an unprivileged location (such as your `$HOME`).

Comment: @Kusalananda it's a pretty safe bet that any system where the sysadmins have removed or not-installed perl will have done the same thing for gcc and any other compiler and/or unwanted language.   `xmlstarlet` could be compiled on another compatible system and installed under $HOME...but doing that on such a tightly controlled system will probably annoy the admins.  It may even be a sackable offence to install any software on a production server without authorisation.  Some sites are extremely rigid about change management, and/or have strict regulations they have to comply with (e.g. banks)

Comment: IMO the best option here is to copy the XML data to a system were you have a good set of tools (including xmlstarlet and/or perl) to process it with.  If such copying is allowed, of course.

Comment: @cas If management has reasons to tie down a set of machines so tightly that it forces a developer to come up with a shoddy and non-robust hack to solve a production issue, then there are inadequacies in the management of the project.

Answer (score 2):

### Sed solution

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -nr '
    /^<[^<]*>$/ {
        N
        /^<([^<]*)>\n<\/\1>$/=
    }
' "$1" | awk '{print "Output: "$NF - 1" -> line number"}'
```

#### Explanation:

1. `sed`

   - `/^<[^<]*>$/` if we are have one open tag in the line
   - `N` - append the next line of input into the pattern space.
   - `/^<([^<]*)>\n<\/\1>$/` and check, does the next line have the equivalent closed tag.
   - if so, print this line number by `=` command. Bear in mind, that it is the closed tag line number. We should decrease it by one in further.
2. `awk` - decreases the line number and print it in the message string.

#### Testing:

**Input**

```
<a>
</a>
<a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
<c>
</c>
</a>
```

**Output**

```
./empty_tag.sh input.txt 
Output: 1 -> line number
Output: 6 -> line number
```

---

### AWK solution

**Usage:** `./empty_tag.sh input.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[>/]' '
    line_num {
        if(NF == 3) {print "Output: " line_num " -> line number";}
        line_num = 0;
    }
    NF == 2 {line_num = NR;}
' "$1"
```

Comment: Why output has 6 line number ? I need empty <a> </a> tag alone

Comment: @user7952074 I added another one empty tag for testing - `<c></c>` on the 6 line.

Comment: ok thanks ! If possible Please explain so every one would get it.

Comment: I get error as r is not recognized and function cannot be parsed.

Comment: @user7952074 Remove `-r` option. Then, brackets should be escaped by backslashes - `/^<\([^<]*\)>\n<\/\1>$/=`

Comment: @user7952074 I added `awk` solution.